Мне нужно из реквизита(ФИО) табличной части(студенты) справочника вытащить данные в реквизит (ФИО) табличной части (студенты) документа

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом, я уже пыталась подставить свои переменные в код, но пишет "поле не найдено".

ЭлСсылка = Справочники.СписокГруппИСтудентов.НайтиПоКоду(1);
Эл = ЭлСсылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
ДокСсылка = Документы.УспеваемостьИПосещаемость.НайтиПоКоду(1);
Док = ДокСсылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
Для Каждого Стр из Эл.Студенты Цикл
   НовСтр = Док.Добавить();
   НовСтр.ФИО = Стр.ФИО;
КонецЦикла;


Выдает ошибку {Документ.УспеваемостьИПосещаемость.Форма.ФормаДокумента.Форма(3,12)}: Переменная не определена (Справочники)
ЭлСсылка = «?»Справочники.СписокГруппИСтудентов.НайтиПоКоду(1); (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)
{Документ.УспеваемостьИПосещаемость.Форма.ФормаДокумента.Форма(5,13)}: Переменная не определена (Документы)
ДокСсылка = «?»Документы.УспеваемостьИПосещаемость.НайтиПоКоду(1); (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)
